# Redirect non-www(http) and www(http) to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, no-www

I am trying to do a redirect from non-www(http) and www(http) to https://www
but it does not work. Need the following to work. Please help

1. http://example.com redirect to https://www.example.com
2. http://www.example.com  redirect to https://www.example.com

Current htaccess file

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]

rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Tried below rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry, but this question has been asked and answered about 65836593659 times alone here on SO. Are you _really_ sure that none of all those answers help? _Why not?_ And why should the 65836593659th answer then make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```